# Is it possible to add setter for inner(nested) fields in dart?

Tags: dart

In dart we can execute some code when value of field is changed using something like

```
class Name{
  String fname;
  String lname;
}
class Person extends ChangeNotifier{
  Name _name = Name();
  set name(Name n){
    notifyListeners();
    _name = n;
  }
  get name=>_name;
}

//inside main() 
Person p = Person();
p.name = Name();
```

I want to be able to perform similar action while setting inner fields. Such as while doing

```
p.name.fname ="FooBar";
```

But I want to be able to do it from `Person` class.

**Because** I am extending `ChangeNotifier` in Person class. And I want to call

```
notifyListeners()
```

that is not accessible in Name class. This is best I've come up with

```
Name newName = Name(p.name); //copy constructor
newName.fname = "Foo Bar";
p.name = newName;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do depends on how you can constrain the API.

If `Name` objects are routinely being created by third-party code and passed around, and are expected to retain their identity when stored in a `Person` object, then here isn't much you can do. So I wouldn't design the Person object that way.

Instead I'd say that the `Name` object of a `Person` object is linked to that, and setting the `name` of a `Person` is the same as setting both name parts.

Example:

```
class Person {
  _PersonName _name;
  Person(...) : ... {
    _name = _PersonName(this);
  }
  ...
  void set name(Name name) {
    _name.fname = name.fname;
    _name.lname = name.lname;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Name get name => _name;
}

class _PersonName extends Name {
  final Person _owner;
  _PersonName(this._owner);
  void set fname(String fname) {
    super.fname = fname;
    _owner.notifyListeners();
  }
  void set lname(String lname) {
    super.lname = lname;
    _owner.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

That has the disadvantage that the extracted `_PersonName` is forever linked to the `Person` object, even if you try to write a different `Name` object.

Another option is to create a new `_PersonName` on every store a new name object, and detach the old object from the `Person` at that point:

```
class Person {
  _PersonName _name = _PersonName;
  Person(...) : ... {
    _name = _PersonName(this, null, null);
  }
  void set name(Name name) {
    _name.owner = null;
    _name = _PersonName(this, name.fname, name.lname);
    notifyListeners();
  } 
  Name get name => _name;
}
class _PersonName extends Name {
  Person _owner;
  _PersonName(this._owner, String fname, String lname) {
    super.fname = fname;
    super.lname = lname;
  }
  void set fname(String fname) {
    super.fname = fname;
    owner?.notifyListeners();
  }
  void set lname(String lname) {
    super.lname = lname;
    owner?.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This approach behaves mostly like the plain storing of name objects, except that if you do:

var p = Person();
   var n = Name();
   p.name = n;
   print(identical(n, p.name)); // false?

you don't preserve the identity of the `Name` object stored into the `Person` object.
There is no way to do so, and also change the behavior of setting strings directly on the name using `person.name.fname = ...`, so something has to be sacrificed.

Comment: This definitely looks like better approach then one I have. But I'll have to be honest, it was very hard to understand at first.